# Vba autocad, подключение к базе данных

Tags: access, vba, autocad

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста, как можно в autocad средствами vba подключиться к access-файлу-базе

Comment: Вероятно так, как написано в документации. Под рукой её нет, но из того, что помню -- создать объект, какой нибудь ADODB или OLEDB -- сейчас уже не скажу, и с ним работать.

Кстати, google на эту тему даёт сразу кучу ссылок, в том числе и о том, что "AutoCAD 2012 for 64-bit does not support Microsoft Jet 4.0 OLE DB Provider". Но туда не смотрел и не собираюсь. Надеюсь, что Вы это сами можете прочитать.

Comment: Спасибо, в этих ссылках ничего по делу не нашёл, а adodb не поддерживается(

Comment: Увы. Не AutoCAD'а под рукой. Да и виндов-то нет... Не поддерживается ADODB... А другие варианты, напр. OLEDB? И ещё, кем не поддерживается adodb? Вашими виндами?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Что-то нашёл, нужно в редакторе VBA подключить референсы на библиотеки, tools->references

там подрубить microsoft DAO
хотя я подключил всё, где упомяналось DB, Database, Access, на всякий случай))))

далее код для моего случая

```
Dim db As Variant
Dim ws As Variant
Dim rs As Variant

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = ws.opendatabase("E:\SizesDB.mdb")
Set rs = db.openrecordset("Sizes") ' подключаемся

Dim data(20, 10) As String ' у меня числа в базе, но это же VBA, прокатит:))
rs.movefirst ' тут читаем первую запись

Dim count As Integer

Do While Not rs.EOF ' цикл пока не дойдёт до конца
    data(count, 0) = rs!b0 ' b0 - имя поля
    data(count, 1) = rs!L  ' L - имя поля
    data(count, 2) = rs!B
    data(count, 3) = rs!H
    data(count, 4) = rs!A
    data(count, 5) = rs!l0
    data(count, 6) = rs!l1
    data(count, 7) = rs!l2
    data(count, 8) = rs!l2
    data(count, 9) = rs!r

    rs.movenext ' идём к следующей записи

    count = count + 1
Loop
```

Вариант не очень красивый, но хоть что-то

источник:
http://www.pseudology.org/cad/atp608a.pdf